# Embed Word, PPT, and Excel in a Website

Tags: excel, ms-word, web, embed, powerpoint

I'm trying to embed Word, PPT, and Excel files on a website.

I've tried Google docs and Microsoft Office 365 but I had the following issues with them:

- If I'm not signed in using my Gmail account for many days, the embedded document won't show up. Also, sometimes it says that I've reached the maximum number of views for the current document.
- Microsoft office 365's problem is that it adds big top and bottom bars to the documents and they come with colors (red, green, and blue)..which makes the website look very ugly

Comment: I am also trying to embed office 365 apps in our web application. How did you attempt the integration? By adding the url inside an iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install LibreOffice on your server and do the conversions from any doc files to PDF automatically.
An alternative is using VeryPDF.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this? It adds a bar at the bottom but that's required to navigate the slideshow

http://www.microsoft.com/web/solutions/powerpoint-embed.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did, but I don't want to embed the files by manually uploading them on Skydrive or anywhere else. I want to add it to a URL (as what google docs preview does) and then embed it on the website (example: ...src="...pdf")